# Rails + ActiveStorage on S3: Set filename on download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, filenames, rails-activestorage

Is there a way to change/set the filename on download?

Example: Jon Smith uploaded his headshot, and the filename is `4321431-small.jpg`. On download, I'd like to rename the file to `jon_smith__headshot.jpg`.

View:
`<%= url_for user.headshot_file %>`

This `url_for` downloads the file from Amazon S3, but with the original filename.

What are my options here?

Comment: What is the code for the download?

Comment: url_for user.headshot_file as stated in the description. url_for provides the download URL automatically.

Comment: Have you tried `<%= url_for user.headshot_file, filename: "jon_smith__headshot.jpg" %>`

Comment: url_for takes only one argument.

Comment: Does it need to be `url_for`? You could write a `link_to` with a download image method. Or, you could rename the file name before saving it to S3.

Comment: File gets saved to S3 directly via JS before the data gets to the controller so I am working on updating the filename in the blob on successful save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach of @GuilPejon will work. The problem with directly calling the `service_url` is:

1. It is short-lived (not recommended by rails team)
2. It will not work if the service is `disk` in development mode.

The reason it does not work for disk service is that disk service requires `ActiveStorage::Current.host` to be present for generating the URL. And `ActiveStorage::Current.host` gets set in `app/controllers/active_storage/base_controller.rb`, so it will be missing when `service_url` gets called.

ActiveStorage as of now gives one more way of accessing the URL of the attachments:

1. Using `rails_blob_(url|path)` (recommended way)

But if you use this, you can only provide `content-disposition` and not the filename.

If you see the `config/routes.rb` in the `ActiveStorage repo you will find the below code.

```
    get "/rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename" => "active_storage/blobs#show", as: :rails_service_blob

    direct :rails_blob do |blob, options|
        route_for(:rails_service_blob, blob.signed_id, blob.filename, options)
    end
```

and when you look into `blobs_controller` you will find the below code:

```
    def show
        expires_in ActiveStorage::Blob.service.url_expires_in
        redirect_to @blob.service_url(disposition: params[:disposition])
    end
```

So it is clear that in `rails_blob_(url|path)` you can only pass `disposition` and nothing more.

Comment: service_url takes expires_in option that - I guess - can be used to manipulate the lifetime of the url.

Answer (score 6):

The built-in controller serves blobs with their stored filenames. You can implement a custom controller that serves them with a different filename:

```
class HeadshotsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  def show
    redirect_to @user.headshot.service_url(filename: filename)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def filename
      ActiveStorage::Filename.new("#{user.name.parameterize(separator: "_")}__headshot#{user.headshot.filename.extension_with_delimiter}")
    end
end
```

Starting with 5.2.0 RC2, you won’t need to pass an `ActiveStorage::Filename`; you can pass a `String` filename instead.

Comment: Thank you, this approach works and I am accepting it as the answer. The missing piece for me was using `model.attachment_field.service_url filename: filename` where `filename` is an `ActiveStorage::Filename`. That being said, I will likely implement a simpler solution which does not require a separate controller and route for each attachment type.

Answer (score 5):

I know this was already answered, but I would like to add a second way of doing this. You could update your file name when the user object is saved. Using OP's example of the `user` model and the `headshot_file` field, this is how you could solve this:

```rb
# app/models/user.rb

after_save :set_filename

def set_filename
  file.blob.update(filename: "ANYTHING_YOU_WANT.#{file.filename.extension}") if file.attached?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using external storage with AWS S3. Our goal was to change the file path on S3. The solution for us was to change the blob `key` before save:

```rb
before_save :set_filename
  
def set_filename
  if self.custom_file.attached?
    self.custom_file.blob.update(key: "#{Time.now.to_i}-custom-#{name}.#{self.custom_file.filename.extension}".parameterize)
  end
end
```

Usage: `custom_file.url`

##### Update

`Time.now.to_i` is required otherwise you could get unique index constraints when you try to upload a 2nd file to overwrite the first file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with ActiveStorage yet, so this is kind of a shot in the dark.

Looking at the ActiveStorage [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb#L61) for the S3 service, it looks like you can specify the filename and disposition for the upload. From the [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files) it seems that you can use `rails_blob_path` to access the raw URL of the upload and pass these parameters. Therefor you might try:

```
rails_blob_url(user.headshot_file, filename: "jon_smith__headshot.jpg")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as advertised. It produces a link in the format of `http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/ey...c/new_filename.png.old_filename.png"` which on download saves the file as `old_filename.png`. I think right now renaming the filenames in the blob is my best bet.

Comment: Active Storage doesn’t use the filename in the download URL. It’s there to accommodate older browsers that don’t respect the filename in the `Content-Disposition` header.